# Using a variable as the column name in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to turn this:

```
"SELECT username FROM $table WHERE username='$newName'"
```

Into this:

```
"SELECT $column FROM $table WHERE $column='$newName'"
```

But when I use `or die()` on it, I get an error saying that there is incorrect syntax near `WHERE username='someNameHere'`. What is the correct way to substitute the column name, assuming that's what's wrong?

**Edit:** Code is just this. The values should be correct as I don't see any mispellings in the error.

```
$sql = "SELECT $column FROM $table WHERE $column='$newName'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
```

Comment: Show us your code, i don't get you about 'when i use or die() on it'.

Comment: That should work. Are you sure your variables contain expected values?

Comment: What does `echo $sql;` show?

Comment: Please, stop using the _Deprecated_ `mysql_*` extension, switch to `PDO` or `mysqli_*`, and start using prepared statements, and make sure there are no spaces, quotes or backticks in the variables

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ah, thank you, it was the `$table` part that got overwritten some lines before this but I just kept concentrating on the `$column` part.

Answer (score 8):

Make your query like this

```
$sql = "SELECT ".$column." FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$column."='".$newName."'"
```

BTW this is SQLinjection vulnerable code. You should check the variables before using them in query. Also you should start using [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT ".$column." FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$column."=".$newName;
```

Check to see if that works for you.