# Select * from table_name where column_nameِ = 'value'

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table (table A) with 6 column(days,les1,les2,les3,les4,les5)

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  days  |  les1  |  les2  |  les3  |  les4  |  les5  |
-------------------------------------------------------
| sat    |   2    |   5    |   9    |   10   |   30   |
| mon    |   50   |   2    |   2    |   4    |   5    |
| Fri    |   6    |   1    |   2    |   8    |   4    |
| wed    |   8    |   0    |   3    |   6    |   3    |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

in another table (table B) i have 3 column(id,TName,LName)

```
 ___________________________
|  id    |  TName |  LName |
----------------------------
| 1      |   M.N  |   les1 |
| 2      |   T.G  |   les5 |
| 3      |   Z.GH |   les2 | 
| 4      |   J.H  |   les4 | 
----------------------------
```

i need to find some value from  table A with a code in php,something like this code :

```
  $les = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_B` WHERE `id` = '3' ");

     $les_f = mysql_fetch_array($les);

    $lesson = $les_f['LName'];  //so the $lesson value = 'les2'  

    $list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_A` WHERE $lesson = '0' ");
     $showresult = mysql_fetch_array($list);

$result = $showresult['days'];  //  it should show me 'wed' from tableA in days column
```

please help to write this code...

Comment: I don't see any primary/foreign key relation between your tables

Comment: my tables are just two example...primary key for both table is 'id' and i forget to write this in table A .... my question is this: select * from 'table a' where "a variable" = something

Comment: You have sample data.  What results are you trying to get?  And what do the columns mean?

Comment: This looks like bad database architecture if you store the column name of Table A in Table B. Why don't you reduce Table A to 3 columns 'day', 'number', 'les'?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i need to know this : SELECT * FROM 'table_A' WHERE a variable in my php code = 'Value'....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable as the column name in a mysql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449014/using-a-variable-as-the-column-name-in-a-mysql-query)

Comment: And what's wrong with the php code you included in the question? (apart from the fact that it uses mysql_*() functions)

Comment: A database table is not a spreadsheet. See normalization. Any time you have enumerated columns, alarm bells should start ringing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to improve your database design. Reduce your columns of Table A to `day, number, les` and Table B to `id, TName, LId`

Table A should look like this:

```
+---------------------------+
|  day   | number |  les   |
----------------------------
| sat    |   2    |   1    |
| sat    |   5    |   2    |
| sat    |   9    |   3    |
| sat    |  10    |   4    |
| sat    |  30    |   5    |
|        |        |        |
| mon    |  50    |   1    |
| mon    |   2    |   2    |
| mon    |   2    |   3    |
| mon    |   8    |   4    |
| mon    |   5    |   5    |
| ...    | ...    |  ...   |
----------------------------
```

Table B should look like this:

```
|  id    |  TName |  LId |
----------------------------
| 1      |   M.N  |      1 |
| 2      |   T.G  |      5 |
| 3      |   Z.GH |      2 | 
| 4      |   J.H  |      4 | 
----------------------------
```

Then you can fetch your data with a single SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_b b
    JOIN table_a a
    ON b.les = a.LId
    WHERE a.number = 0
```

Comment: why? you suggest me erase the QUESTION? ;-)   LETS try another question : i have a select query == > "SELECT * FROM table_A  WHERE  ".$som." = '4' "       ok?  and lets think $som = 'les' ; ....it should work...but in my code it didnt work...why????

Comment: I just pointed out, that your database design isn't that good. What are the error messages you are getting? Because your piece of code looks good.

Comment: thank you...i'll change my database design.....code looks good...but when i use this there is no result !!  i use this code in TELEGRAM bot...telegram get a code from user and then search this in my database ...if find something...show the values in keyborad for user...when is write this code :  "SELECT * FROM 'TABLE_A' WHERE 'les2' =  '1' "....i will get result....but when i use this : "SELECT * FROM 'TABLE_A' WHERE ".$som." =  '1' ".  and $som = 'les2'  ..... there is no result

Comment: Did you check for mysql Errors with [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $les = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_B` WHERE `id` = '3' ");

     $les_f = mysql_fetch_array($les);

    $lesson = $les_f['LName'];  //so the $lesson value = 'les2'  

    $list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_A` WHERE $lesson = '0' ");
     $showresult = mysql_fetch_array($list);

$result = $showresult['days'];
```

CHANGE :

```
$list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_A` WHERE $lesson = '0' ");
```

TO :

```
 $list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_A` WHERE `".$lesson."` = '0' ");
```

IS this question solution

Comment: Actually SQL-Statements shouldn't require quoting unless you are using reserved keywords. Don't see what the problem was here.

Answer (score -1):

try below code fatch the result

```
$les = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_B` WHERE `id` = '3' ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($les)) {
    $lesson = $row['LName'];  //so the $lesson value = 'les2'  
    $list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_A` WHERE $lesson = '0' ");
    while($showresult = mysql_fetch_assoc($list)) {
        echo $result = $showresult['days'];  //  it should show me 'wed' from tableA in days column 
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Database architecture is wrong. this code will work but it will performance will get down. I suggest change your database structure.